# Repeater table interface change in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

i have a project where first user upload some documents and then admin approves it.... i show documents in repeater table and use it  so when admin log in and click on submit button for approving documents like this please check pic
like this:

[image: TABLE PIC]

and when i click on submit button then table entirely changes a different  look like this it show some thing like a very long columns:

[image: WHEN CLICK ON BUTTON THEN TABLE CHANGE]

this is ASPX.CS PAGE

```
<div class="CSSTableGenerator">
    <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="results">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" OnItemCommand="Repeater2_ItemCommand"
            runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater2_ItemDataBound">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <%--<td></td>--%>
                    <td>DocumentID</td>
                    <td>Document Name</td>
                    <td>File Name</td>
                    <td>Uploaded By</td>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>Department</td>
                    <td>Status</td>
                </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="DocId" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocID")%>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="DocName" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocName")%>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="Uploadfile" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Uploadfile")%>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UploadedBy")%>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="YourEamil" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserEmail")%>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="DepType" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DepType")%>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ApproveID") %>' Visible="false" />
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" class="vpb_dropdown1" DataTextField="ApproveType" DataValueField="ApproveID" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Pending" Selected="selected" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Approve" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Reject" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </table>
</div>
```

THIS IS CSS

```
.CSSTableGenerator {
    margin:0px;padding:0px;
    width:100%;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;

    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;

    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;

    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;

    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
}.CSSTableGenerator table{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;padding:0px;
}.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
}
.CSSTableGenerator table tr:first-child td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
}
.CSSTableGenerator table tr:first-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
}.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td:first-child{
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
}.CSSTableGenerator tr:hover td{
    background-color:#d3e9ff;


}
.CSSTableGenerator td{
    vertical-align:middle;

    background-color:#aad4ff;

    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:7px;
    font-size:9px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#000000;
}.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td{
    border-width:0px 1px 0px 0px;
}.CSSTableGenerator tr td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child td{
        background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #0057af 5%, #0057af 100%);    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #0057af), color-stop(1, #0057af) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #0057af 5%, #0057af 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#0057af", endColorstr="#0057af");  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#0057af,0057af);

    background-color:#0057af;
    border:0px solid #ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
    font-size:9px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child:hover td{
    background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #0057af 5%, #0057af 100%);    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #0057af), color-stop(1, #0057af) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #0057af 5%, #0057af 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#0057af", endColorstr="#0057af");  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#0057af,0057af);

    background-color:#0057af;
}
.CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child td:first-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}
.CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
}

   .CSSTableGenerator span {font-size:9px;} 
               .CSSTableGenerator  td
            {
                  padding-left: 4px;     
                  padding-right: 4px;    
              }
```

can any one here please tell me where is the probelm occur?

Comment: Please provide html source it would be more helpful

Comment: And the relevant CSS, if any.

Comment: This looks like either a styling issue with CSS, or possibly strange content is being inserted into your labels. The .NET ASPX code is not particularly relevant: show us your HTML source and CSS after the Submit clicked.

Comment: I ALREADY POSTED HTML @KAMLESH

Comment: please check my update quesion i post css...

Answer (score 0):

```
.CSSTableGenerator table{
width:100%;
height:inherit;
margin:0px;padding:0px;
}
```

replace height value 100% with inherit